# Cauchy problem: $y '(x) + (\tanh x) y(x) = \sinh x$, $y(0) = 1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am using the formula for the inhomogeneous first order differential equation but I don't know how to apply the Cauchy problem to it. Like I still have the $c$ constant with this inhomogeneous first order and I don't know how to manipulate it.

We are given $y(0) = 1$ so do I just replace the $c$ with that?

Answer (score 1):

if you multiply by $\cosh x,$ you have $$\cosh x \sinh x = \cosh x y' + \sinh x y = (y\cosh x)' $$ integrating from $0$ to $x,$ we have $$\frac 12 \int_0^x \sinh 2x \, dx = y\cosh x -  1 \to y =\frac{1+\frac14(\cosh 2x - 1)}{\cosh x}=\frac{\cosh 2x + 3}{4\cosh x} $$

Comment: You've done once again, good buddy!  ***Endorsed!!!***

Comment: Just like I would have!

Answer (score 0):

The integrating factor is $e^{\int \tanh(x) dx}=e^{\ln(\cosh(x))}=\cosh(x)$. So your equation becomes

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left ( y(x) \cosh(x) \right ) = \sinh(x) \cosh(x).$$

Now you need to integrate both sides and divide out the $\cosh$ on the left side. Alternately you can use a definite integral, in which case you get

$$y(x) \cosh(x) - y(0) \cosh(0) = \int_0^x \sinh(z) \cosh(z) dz.$$